# How to Redirect if no mouse movement and show current timer countown

Tags: javascript, session-timeout, jquery-events

I have this javascript to act as a countdown timer in a div, and simultaneously detecting mouse idleness.

```
  var timer = null;

 setInterval(function() {
            var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
            var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
            div.textContent = count;
            if (count == 0) {
                window.location.href="https://example.com";
            }
        }, 1000);

 function goAway() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href="https://example.com";
    }, 5000);
}  
window.addEventListener('mousemove', goAway, true); 
goAway();
```

If the user makes no mouse movement for more than 5 seconds, I want him to be redirected to another page. The example.com in this case. This part is working. However, I also intent for a right placed div to show the countdown to be redirected, and to disappear in case of **.mousemove** event. I cannot seem to get both of them working.

is it possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/9sAce/

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing wrong. We need to know what isn't working before we can help fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. A few modifications done to `goAway` function.

```js
var timer = null;
 
setInterval(function() {
 var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
 var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
 div.textContent = count;
 if (count == 0) {
  window.location.href="https://example.com";
 }
}, 1000);
        
function goAway() {
    var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
    div.innerText = "10";
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       if (div.innerText === "0")
            window.location.href="https://example.com";
    }, 5000);
}  

window.addEventListener('mousemove', goAway, true); 

goAway();
```

```html
<div id="counter" style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
function countdown(outputElement, seconds){
  var s = 5, bs = 5;
  if(seconds){
    s = bs = seconds;
  }
  function tF(){
    outputElement.innerHTML = s = bs;
    return setInterval(function(){
      s--;
      if(!s){
        clearInterval(timer); location = 'https://example.com';
      }
      outputElement.innerHTML = s;
    }, 1000);
  }
  var timer = tF();
  onmousemove = function(){
    clearInterval(timer); timer = tF();
  }
}
var old = onload;
onload = function(){
if(old)old();
countdown(document.getElementById('counter'));
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#counter{
  font-size:80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>simple countdown</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='counter'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That style of assignment is fine, just not when you initialize vars.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to modifiy this timer because it already worked with what I needed but I'm having trouble. I altered the tF function and made it open a window instead of redirecting, however I would also want it to check if the tab was already opened via click. And in that case, don't open it. Could you help me?

Comment: Just test to see if the var you assign the new window to is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Configurable:

Swap out .timer for #counter if that's your preference.

`t` tracks time

`l` is total time

`h` is url

Inside the interval `n` is the total time minus the current time `t`

`v` compares the calculation greater than 0 if false set `n` to 0 ( needed to prevent negative integers )

Update the DOM with the visual count

if `n` is equal to 0 redirect to the set URL.

```
(()=>{
    t = 0;
    l = 5;
    h = 'https://example.com';

    document.write('<h1 class="timer">'+l+'</h1>');
    timer = document.querySelector('.timer');

    setInterval(()=>{
        t += 1;
        n = (l - t);
        v = n > 0 ? n : 0;
        timer.innerText = v;

        if(n === 0) {
            window.location.href = h;
        }
    }, 1000);

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        t = 0;
    });

})();
```

[Click here to see an example:](https://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/VMVMLa) https://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/VMVMLa

Comment: this works except that the timer only resets to 4 instead of 5

Comment: The timer explicitly says 5 as you can see in 5 set in the variable l. You may take a second to load the page, the script executes as soon as it's loaded so you may not see the number 5.